# How can I access object in Mixin via dispatch?

Tags: django

So I am trying to use Mixin, and the aim is to check if the requester is the owner of the object (owner is a field in my model).

However, I am unable to do such a thing, with a result of `'TweetsUpdateView' object has no attribute 'object'`, what is wrong in my code?

My models

```
class Tweets(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False, default="", max_length=255)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="owner_tweets_set",
    )
    user_likes = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

My view

```
class OwnerRequiredMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.object.owner != self.request.user:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(OwnerRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)


class TweetsUpdateView(
    LoginRequiredMixin,
    OwnerRequiredMixin,
    UpdateView,
):
    model = Tweets
    # fields = ["description"]
    # template_name = "tweets_form.html"
    template_name_suffix = "_form"
    form_class = TweetForm

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print("form is invalid")
        return HttpResponse("form is invalid.. this is just an HttpResponse object")

    # slug_field = "id"
    # slug_url_kwarg = "tweet_id"
    # success_url = reverse_lazy("tweets:twitter")
    success_url = reverse_lazy("tweets:twitter")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access objects by using   `self.object = self.get_object()`
as it hasn't been called yet